# What range sound frequency can be measured from iPhone's microphone?

Tags: iphone, range, frequency, microphone, voice-recording

I want to know the range of frequency that the iPhone's microphone can listen and can we play the least frequency sound recorded by iPhone's microphone?

Comment: I would guess the only real way to provide this information reliably would be to provide audio using a frequency generator and recording the signal in an appropriate environment using the iPhone.

Comment: Related: [iPhone Microphone Frequency Response Comparison (2009)](http://blog.faberacoustical.com/2009/ios/iphone/iphone-microphone-frequency-response-comparison/), [Over what frequency range can the microphone of smartphone receive the sound?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/59157/11197)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This web site](http://web.archive.org/web/20120502221300/http://www.wirelessinfo.com/content/Apple-iPhone-3G-Cell-Phone-Review/Audio-Quality.htm) has some iPhone 3G frequency response curves.  Different device models have different mic frequency responses.

You can use any of AVRecorder, AudioQueue or AudioUnit RemoteIO APIs to record audio.  See Apple's SpeakHere example app which includes source code for recording and saving to a file.